# Why won't the JavaScript work uiwebview?

Tags: ios, firebase, uiwebview, swift2, firebase-authentication

I'm creating an iOS app and Website for a project I'm working on. The website uses Firebase for user authentication. The app uses Swift 2.

The website allows me to sign up or log in from any browser. The app however, is supposed to open the website and allow me to log in or sign up but it doesn't. (I know, I can just use Swift and Firebase to build the app, but this project is different). Here's the code, I don't understand the error here.

App Code

```
@IBOutlet weak var myWebView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = NSURL (string: "https://crowdtest1.herokuapp.com/index.html");
    let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
    myWebView.loadRequest(requestObj);    
}
```